# Lightgbm Fatal error: Unknown token in data file

Tags: lightgbm

I am training a model with LightGBM where I am getting the following error that happens without a pattern (sometimes the training finish without any error on the same exact input data).

```
[LightGBM] [Fatal] Unknown token a-05 in data file
[LightGBM] [Warning] Unknown token a-05 in data file
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::runtime_error'
  what():  Unknown token a-05 in data file
Aborted (core dumped)
```

My best guess is that this error has something to do with the physical memory.